# How to dynamically create nested infinite sub nested array of objects based on nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a scenario where i have to build a deep nested navigation with infinite levels based on parent child response. i tried to write a recursive function to solve this issue but it work with 2 levels but not after that. The function is working fine i keep settings out but i make it a sub child of talent then its returning empty array.

current input:

```
{
    "d": [
        {
            "name": null,
            "type": null,
            "description": null,
            "route": {
                "key": "talent",
                "icon": "SupervisorAccountIcon",
                "name": "Talent",
                "type": "collapse"
            },
            "navigationId": null,
            "moduleId": 1,
            "sub_navigations": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": null,
                    "type": null,
                    "description": null,
                    "route": {
                        "key": "job-management",
                        "icon": "EngineeringIcon",
                        "name": "Job Management"
                    },
                    "createdAt": "2022-06-27T16:59:57.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z",
                    "deletedAt": null,
                    "navigationId": 3,
                    "moduleId": 1,
                    "sub_navigations": [
                        {
                            "id": 5,
                            "name": "Manage Segments",
                            "type": null,
                            "description": null,
                            "route": {
                                "key": "manage-segments",
                                "name": "Manage Segments",
                                "type": "collapse",
                                "route": "/views/manage-segments",
                                "comp_name": "ManageSegments"
                            },
                            "createdAt": "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z",
                            "deletedAt": null,
                            "navigationId": 4,
                            "moduleId": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 6,
                            "name": "Manage Values",
                            "type": null,
                            "description": null,
                            "route": {
                                "key": "manage-values",
                                "name": "Manage Values",
                                "type": "collapse",
                                "route": "/views/manage-values",
                                "comp_name": "ManageValues"
                            },
                            "createdAt": "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z",
                            "deletedAt": null,
                            "navigationId": 4,
                            "moduleId": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 12,
                            "name": "Job Description",
                            "type": null,
                            "description": null,
                            "route": {
                                "key": "job-description",
                                "name": "Job Description",
                                "type": "collapse",
                                "route": "views/job-description",
                                "comp_name": "JobDescription",
                                "isVisible": false
                            },
                            "properties": null,
                            "createdAt": "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z",
                            "deletedAt": null,
                            "navigationId": 4,
                            "moduleId": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 13,
                            "name": "Manage Jobs",
                            "type": null,
                            "description": null,
                            "route": {
                                "key": "manage-jobs",
                                "name": "Manage Jobs",
                                "type": "collapse",
                                "route": "/views/manage-jobs",
                                "comp_name": "ManageJobs"
                            },
                            "createdAt": "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z",
                            "deletedAt": null,
                            "navigationId": 4,
                            "moduleId": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": null,
                    "type": null,
                    "description": null,
                    "route": {
                        "key": "settings",
                        "icon": "SettingsIcon",
                        "name": "Settings",
                        "type": "collapse"
                    },
                    "navigationId": null,
                    "moduleId": 1,
                    "sub_navigations": [
                        {
                            "id": 8,
                            "name": null,
                            "type": null,
                            "description": null,
                            "route": {
                                "key": "setup-and-maintenance",
                                "icon": "SettingsIcon",
                                "name": "Setup & Maintenance",
                                "type": "collapse"
                            },
                            "properties": null,
                            "createdAt": "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z",
                            "deletedAt": null,
                            "navigationId": 7,
                            "moduleId": 1,
                            "sub_navigations": [
                                {
                                    "id": 9,
                                    "name": "Organization Structure",
                                    "type": null,
                                    "description": null,
                                    "route": {
                                        "key": "org-struct",
                                        "name": "Structure Management",
                                        "type": "collapse",
                                        "route": "/views/org-struct",
                                        "comp_name": "ManageOrgStructure"
                                    },
                                    "createdAt": "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z",
                                    "updatedAt": "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z",
                                    "deletedAt": null,
                                    "navigationId": 8,
                                    "moduleId": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 10,
                                    "name": "Manage Roles",
                                    "type": null,
                                    "description": null,
                                    "route": {
                                        "key": "manage-roles",
                                        "name": "Functional Security",
                                        "type": "collapse",
                                        "route": "/views/manage-roles",
                                        "comp_name": "ManageRoles"
                                    },
                                    "createdAt": "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z",
                                    "updatedAt": "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z",
                                    "deletedAt": null,
                                    "navigationId": 8,
                                    "moduleId": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 14,
                                    "name": "Manage Workflow Access",
                                    "type": null,
                                    "description": null,
                                    "route": {
                                        "key": "manage-workflow-access",
                                        "name": "Approval Setup",
                                        "type": "collapse",
                                        "route": "/views/manage-workflow-access",
                                        "comp_name": "ManageWorkflowAccess"
                                    },
                                    "createdAt": "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z",
                                    "updatedAt": "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z",
                                    "deletedAt": null,
                                    "navigationId": 8,
                                    "moduleId": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 17,
                                    "name": "Navigation",
                                    "type": null,
                                    "description": null,
                                    "route": {
                                        "key": "navigations",
                                        "name": "UI Properties",
                                        "type": "collapse",
                                        "route": "/views/navigations",
                                        "comp_name": "Navigations"
                                    },
                                    "createdAt": "2022-08-01T07:20:16.000Z",
                                    "updatedAt": "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z",
                                    "deletedAt": null,
                                    "navigationId": 8,
                                    "moduleId": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Users",
            "type": null,
            "description": null,
            "route": {
                "key": "users",
                "icon": "AccountCircleIcon",
                "name": "Users and Data Security",
                "type": "collapse",
                "route": "/views/users",
                "comp_name": "User",
                "noCollapse": true
            },
            "navigationId": null,
            "moduleId": 1,
            "sub_navigations": []
        }
    ]
]
```

Current Implementation:

```
const dynamicNavigations = async (navigations, pagePermissions) => {
    const finalRoutes = []
    for (const nav of navigations)
    {
        const navJson = await isValidJSON(nav.route)
        if (nav.sub_navigations && nav.sub_navigations.length > 0) {
            navJson['collapse'] = []
            navJson['collapse'] = await dynamicNavigations(nav.sub_navigations, pagePermissions)
            finalRoutes.push(navJson)
        }
        else{
            if (await findPageByKey(pagePermissions, navJson))
                finalRoutes.push(await isValidJSON(navJson))
        }
    }

    return finalRoutes
}
```

Current Output:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "key": "talent",
            "icon": "SupervisorAccountIcon",
            "name": "Talent",
            "type": "collapse",
            "collapse": [
                {
                    "key": "job-management",
                    "icon": "EngineeringIcon",
                    "name": "Job Management",
                    "collapse": [
                        {
                            "key": "manage-segments",
                            "name": "Manage Segments",
                            "type": "collapse",
                            "route": "/views/manage-segments",
                            "comp_name": "ManageSegments"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "manage-values",
                            "name": "Manage Values",
                            "type": "collapse",
                            "route": "/views/manage-values",
                            "comp_name": "ManageValues"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "job-description",
                            "name": "Job Description",
                            "type": "collapse",
                            "route": "views/job-description",
                            "comp_name": "JobDescription",
                            "isVisible": false
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "manage-jobs",
                            "name": "Manage Jobs",
                            "type": "collapse",
                            "route": "/views/manage-jobs",
                            "comp_name": "ManageJobs"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": "settings",
                    "icon": "SettingsIcon",
                    "name": "Settings",
                    "type": "collapse",
                    "collapse": [
                        {
                            "key": "setup-and-maintenance",
                            "icon": "SettingsIcon",
                            "name": "Setup & Maintenance",
                            "type": "collapse",
                            "collapse": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "icon": "AccountCircleIcon",
            "name": "Users and Data Security",
            "type": "collapse",
            "route": "/views/users",
            "comp_name": "User",
            "noCollapse": true
        }
    ]
}
```

expected output:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "key": "talent",
            "icon": "SupervisorAccountIcon",
            "name": "Talent",
            "type": "collapse",
            "collapse": [
                {
                    "key": "job-management",
                    "icon": "EngineeringIcon",
                    "name": "Job Management",
                    "collapse": [
                        {
                            "key": "manage-segments",
                            "name": "Manage Segments",
                            "type": "collapse",
                            "route": "/views/manage-segments",
                            "comp_name": "ManageSegments"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "manage-values",
                            "name": "Manage Values",
                            "type": "collapse",
                            "route": "/views/manage-values",
                            "comp_name": "ManageValues"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "job-description",
                            "name": "Job Description",
                            "type": "collapse",
                            "route": "views/job-description",
                            "comp_name": "JobDescription",
                            "isVisible": false
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "manage-jobs",
                            "name": "Manage Jobs",
                            "type": "collapse",
                            "route": "/views/manage-jobs",
                            "comp_name": "ManageJobs"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": "settings",
                    "icon": "SettingsIcon",
                    "name": "Settings",
                    "type": "collapse",
                    "collapse": [
                        {
                            "key": "setup-and-maintenance",
                            "icon": "SettingsIcon",
                            "name": "Setup & Maintenance",
                            "type": "collapse",
                            "collapse": [
                                {
                                    "key": "org-struct",
                                    "name": "Structure Management",
                                    "type": "collapse",
                                    "route": "/views/org-struct",
                                    "comp_name": "ManageOrgStructure"
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "manage-roles",
                                    "name": "Functional Security",
                                    "type": "collapse",
                                    "route": "/views/manage-roles",
                                    "comp_name": "ManageRoles"
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "manage-workflow-access",
                                    "name": "Approval Setup",
                                    "type": "collapse",
                                    "route": "/views/manage-workflow-access",
                                    "comp_name": "ManageWorkflowAccess"
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "navigations",
                                    "name": "UI Properties",
                                    "type": "collapse",
                                    "route": "/views/navigations",
                                    "comp_name": "Navigations"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "icon": "AccountCircleIcon",
            "name": "Users and Data Security",
            "type": "collapse",
            "route": "/views/users",
            "comp_name": "User",
            "noCollapse": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Any Help or guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, your input is what you labeled `current data`, but what you want as output is what you labeled `expected data with deep indefinite nesting` or what you labeled `expected output` ?

Comment: @KaKi87 current data means current input and expected data means what can/will be the expected input and result of expected data should/will be based on expected input/data and vice versa.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it  What do you want the function to handle as input and to return as output ?

Comment: please add raw data and the final result.

Answer (score 1):

For formatting you could just take `route` and map possible `sub_navigations` as `collapse`.

```js
const
    format = ({ route, sub_navigations: sub }) =>
        ({ ...route, ...(sub?.length && { collapse: sub.map(format) }) }),
    data = { d: [{ name: null, type: null, description: null, route: { key: "talent", icon: "SupervisorAccountIcon", name: "Talent", type: "collapse" }, navigationId: null, moduleId: 1, sub_navigations: [{ id: 4, name: null, type: null, description: null, route: { key: "job-management", icon: "EngineeringIcon", name: "Job Management" }, createdAt: "2022-06-27T16:59:57.000Z", updatedAt: "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z", deletedAt: null, navigationId: 3, moduleId: 1, sub_navigations: [{ id: 5, name: "Manage Segments", type: null, description: null, route: { key: "manage-segments", name: "Manage Segments", type: "collapse", route: "/views/manage-segments", comp_name: "ManageSegments" }, createdAt: "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z", updatedAt: "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z", deletedAt: null, navigationId: 4, moduleId: 1 }, { id: 6, name: "Manage Values", type: null, description: null, route: { key: "manage-values", name: "Manage Values", type: "collapse", route: "/views/manage-values", comp_name: "ManageValues" }, createdAt: "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z", updatedAt: "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z", deletedAt: null, navigationId: 4, moduleId: 1 }, { id: 12, name: "Job Description", type: null, description: null, route: { key: "job-description", name: "Job Description", type: "collapse", route: "views/job-description", comp_name: "JobDescription", isVisible: false }, properties: null, createdAt: "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z", updatedAt: "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z", deletedAt: null, navigationId: 4, moduleId: 1 }, { id: 13, name: "Manage Jobs", type: null, description: null, route: { key: "manage-jobs", name: "Manage Jobs", type: "collapse", route: "/views/manage-jobs", comp_name: "ManageJobs" }, createdAt: "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z", updatedAt: "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z", deletedAt: null, navigationId: 4, moduleId: 1 }] }, { name: null, type: null, description: null, route: { key: "settings", icon: "SettingsIcon", name: "Settings", type: "collapse" }, navigationId: null, moduleId: 1, sub_navigations: [{ id: 8, name: null, type: null, description: null, route: { key: "setup-and-maintenance", icon: "SettingsIcon", name: "Setup & Maintenance", type: "collapse" }, properties: null, createdAt: "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z", updatedAt: "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z", deletedAt: null, navigationId: 7, moduleId: 1, sub_navigations: [{ id: 9, name: "Organization Structure", type: null, description: null, route: { key: "org-struct", name: "Structure Management", type: "collapse", route: "/views/org-struct", comp_name: "ManageOrgStructure" }, createdAt: "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z", updatedAt: "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z", deletedAt: null, navigationId: 8, moduleId: 1 }, { id: 10, name: "Manage Roles", type: null, description: null, route: { key: "manage-roles", name: "Functional Security", type: "collapse", route: "/views/manage-roles", comp_name: "ManageRoles" }, createdAt: "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z", updatedAt: "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z", deletedAt: null, navigationId: 8, moduleId: 1 }, { id: 14, name: "Manage Workflow Access", type: null, description: null, route: { key: "manage-workflow-access", name: "Approval Setup", type: "collapse", route: "/views/manage-workflow-access", comp_name: "ManageWorkflowAccess" }, createdAt: "2022-06-27T17:00:25.000Z", updatedAt: "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z", deletedAt: null, navigationId: 8, moduleId: 1 }, { id: 17, name: "Navigation", type: null, description: null, route: { key: "navigations", name: "UI Properties", type: "collapse", route: "/views/navigations", comp_name: "Navigations" }, createdAt: "2022-08-01T07:20:16.000Z", updatedAt: "2022-08-25T08:04:04.000Z", deletedAt: null, navigationId: 8, moduleId: 1 }] }] }] }, { name: "Users", type: null, description: null, route: { key: "users", icon: "AccountCircleIcon", name: "Users and Data Security", type: "collapse", route: "/views/users", comp_name: "User", noCollapse: true }, navigationId: null, moduleId: 1, sub_navigations: [] }] },
    result = { data: data.d.map(format) };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: tried but not working if input is this: https://gist.github.com/salmanzafar949/5837803dacb9c9f3a0ed21c61398cc1e

Comment: where is the difference? please take a **small**(!!!) amount of data for the question!

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/sojurevaqu/edit?html,output)

Assuming the `INPUT` variable is defined beforehand :

```js
const
   mapCallback = item => ({
       ...item.route,
       collapse: item.sub_navigations && item.sub_navigations.length ? item.sub_navigations.map(mapCallback) : undefined
   }),
   OUTPUT = {
       data: INPUT.d.map(mapCallback)
   };
```

The `OUTPUT` variable contains exactly what you expect.

Comment: tried but not working if input is this: https://gist.github.com/salmanzafar949/5837803dacb9c9f3a0ed21c61398cc1e

Comment: This input doesn't have the same structure as the one you attached to your question. If you want a function that handles this one, please create a new question and attach the expected output.

Comment: Even with the same input https://gist.github.com/salmanzafar949/5837803dacb9c9f3a0ed21c61398cc1e its not working

Comment: That input works. [Demo](https://jsbin.com/tegoyaviki/edit?html,output)